# How can I get Modal triggered by a loop inside a table working on mobile?

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4

On the desktop, the modal is working fine. However on mobile, the modal launches behind the background, and it constrained by the table (`tbody`) boundaries.

Here is the modal trigger:

```html
<a data-toggle="modal"  href="" data-target="#choose-trainer-modal-<?= $id ?>" value="">예약 </a>
```

the `$id` is running through a loop because I need to trigger a new modal for each row in the table.

Here is the modal which includes `filename.php` inside the same loop where the trigger is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="choose-trainer-modal-<?= $e->id ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm your spot as a trainer</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="iportfolio">
                    <div class="portfolio-desc">
                        <h3><a href=""><?= t_db($e->event_title) ?></a></h3>
                        <span><a href="#"><?= $e->formatted_start_time . " - " . $e->formatted_finish_time; ?></a>,  <a href="#"> <?= $e->event_location ?></a></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p>
                    Choose one of the students on the waitlist.
                </p>
```

If I move the included modal code outside the loop, it won't get called from the trigger

For mobile, how can I make the modal appear outside of the constraints of the table?

Thank you

Comment: what if you give it z-index?

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS try:

```
.modal {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```